# Impossible to Run Ubuntu on Mac, Help!

Tags: dual-boot, usb, live-usb, plymouth, mac-mini

this is my first time here,

I´ve been tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 in my mac mini 2012 without Refit or Refind, only using  the native booting, i use unebootinf to create a booteable usb, but when i restart   the mac, appears a black screen saying this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8ioe.jpg

I used the command shell to create a bootable USB and the results are the same

thankful in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure rEFInd and rEFIt were made because of that.